# AWS EC2 grafana and influxDb

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, influxdb

Is running open source docker hosted influx db in a private subnet aws ec2 secure? How to ensure availability and security when using the docker open source version?

I don't want to buy the enterprise verison of influx db but I want to ensure the most security

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.